# Use liveUSB to access main SSD Kubuntu files?

Tags: kubuntu, sudo, live-usb, tmp

I had an issue with /tmp becoming full preventing me from opening Kubuntu because of an xsession error). I used a liveUSB but I'm unable to access my persistent files from the main Kubuntu install.

How do I set up sudo permissions to be able to access those?

Answer (score -1):

[This link](https://hibbard.eu/prevent-xsession-errors-file-growing-too-large/) discusses how to trim the `.xsession-errors` file, if it grows too large.

Comment: The issue is I cannot login, I figured I would just wipe it but I need some files. Have heard of people using a live usb to access files given user:pass of the main

Comment: Could you just answer the question, at least the other guy actually slightly helped.